# Создание локальной сети и доступа в интернет

Tags: сервер, 1с, lan

Приветствую всех.
Задача создать локальную сеть с компьютером-сервером (1С), принтерами и рабочими станциями. Плюс компьютеры должны иметь доступ в интернет. 
Как я вижу ситуацию: берем роутер (тот который подходит по технологии: витая пара или ADSL), берем коммутатор с нужным количеством портов.
Так как компания не большая, то 24 портовый роутер по за глаза. Но так как очень глубоко в эту тему не погружался, у меня возникает опасения, что взяв ненастраиваемый коммутатор я не смогу прописать ip компьютеров и принтеров. Прошу разъяснения: верны мои утверждения или нет (придется ли мне брать все же настаиваемый коммутатор)? И еще вопрос: с учетом, что к 1С серверу подключается более 5 компов, то желательно ли иметь на коммутаторе порт с поддержкой 1 Гб/с или 100 хватит?

Comment: Могу лишь отметить, что основные задержки при работе с 1С будут не в сети. Люди не заметят разницы.

Comment: Сама 1С рекомендует не менее 100 Мбит/с. Здесь больше зависит от клиентов (толстый / тонкий) используемых конфигураций. Если тонкий клиент нормально себя чувствует при низких скоростях, то для толстого клиента при большом количестве пользователей нужен хороший канал.